# How to evaluate: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+...+n^{p-1}}{n^p}$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

How to evaluate: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+...+n^{p-1}}{n^p}$$

when

$i)$ $p\in\mathbb R,p\neq0$

$ii)\space p=0$

So for $i)$ I tried using Stolz–Cesàro theorem and Binomial theorem and If I didn't mess up I got $1$. But I'm unsure about it, but for $ii)$ and I don't have a clue where to begin with.

Comment: I would use series / integral comparison to bound below and above $1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+…+n^{p-1}$.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2/469886#469886

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+...+n^{p-1}}{n^p}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac jn\right)^{p-1}\frac1n=\int_0^1x^{p-1}dx=\begin{cases}\frac1p,&p\ne0\\\infty,&p=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: For $p=0$, the limit is the sum of the Harmonic series $\{\frac1n\}$. Proofs of its divergence are quite popular; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874382/question-on-a-proof-of-the-divergence-of-harmonic-series?r=SearchResults)

Comment: For $p>0$ you can have a look at [Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^m}{n^{m+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150391) (and the [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/150391)) or [What is the result of $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum^n_{i=1} i^k}{n^{k+1}},\ k \in \mathbb{R} $ and why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478344) (and the [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/478344)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply the *[Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)* for positive real values $p,  p\ne  1$
and consider other values  of $p$ separately.

We consider for $p\in\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+\cdots+n^{p-1}}{n^p}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> **Case $p>1, 0<p<1$:**
>
> If $p>1$ resp. $0<p<1$ the sequence $(n^p)_{n\geq 1}$ is strictly monotone increasing and unbounded. We can apply the *Stolz-Cesàro* theorem by letting
> \begin{align*}
> a_n&=1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+\cdots+n^{p-1}\\
> b_n&=n^p=\underbrace{n^{p-1}+n^{p-1}+\cdots+n^{p-1}}_{n\ \mathrm{ times}}
> \end{align*}
> Since
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{n^p-(n-1)^{p}}\\
> &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{n^p-(n^p-pn^{p-1}+\binom{p}{2}n^{p-2}-\cdots)}\\
> &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{pn^{p-1}-\binom{p}{2}n^{p-2}+\cdots}\\
> &=\frac{1}{p}
> \end{align*}
> we have according to the theorem
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+\cdots+n^{p-1}}{n^p}\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{p}}
> \end{align*}

**Case $p=1$:**

We obtain

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+\cdots+n^{p-1}}{n^p}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^{n\mathrm{\ times}}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n}
\color{blue}{=1}
\end{align*}

> **Case $p=0$:**
>
> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+\cdots+n^{p-1}}{n^p}
> =\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\color{blue}{=\infty}
> \end{align*}
> since the *[harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))* is divergent.

**Case $p<0$:**

We set $q:=-p$ and obtain with $q>0$:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+\cdots+n^{p-1}}{n^p}
=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^q\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{q+1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^{q+1}}\right)\geq \lim_{n\to\infty} n^q
\color{blue}{=\infty}
\end{align*}

> We summarize:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+\cdots+n^{p-1}}{n^p}=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{p}&p>0\\
> \infty&p\leq 0
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

Just write 
$$\dfrac{1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+...+n^{p-1}}{n^p} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{p-1}$$
 and handle it as the limit of a Riemann sum.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't learnt about integration yet and I don't know how to do that :(